# Are the imaginary parts of these Riemann zeta related numbers equal?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, roots, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

While we can't say anything about the real part of these numbers below, maybe it could be possible to say something about the imaginary parts?

Let:

$$A=\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}}{\zeta \left(\frac{k}{n}+s\right)}$$

and:

$$B=\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}}{\zeta \left(\frac{k}{n}+s+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$

Then compute:

$$\rho_1=\frac{1}{1-\frac{A}{B}}+\frac{1}{n}+s$$

$$\rho_2=\frac{1}{1-\frac{B}{A}}-\frac{1}{n}-s$$

where $s$ is a complex number.

> Show that $\Im(\rho_1)=-\Im(\rho_2)$ for all positive integers $n>1$.

Associated Mathematica program:

```
"Mathematica start"
"Part 1:"
Clear[s, A, B, n, z, k, rho1, rho2];
n = 30;
s = (1/3 + 14*I);
A = Sum[(-1)^(k - 1)*Binomial[n - 1, k - 1]/Zeta[s + k/n], {k, 1, 
   n}]; B = 
 Sum[(-1)^(k - 1)*Binomial[n - 1, k - 1]/Zeta[s + k/n + 1/n], {k, 1, 
   n}]; rho1 = N[(s + 1/n + 1/(1 - A/B)), 30]
rho2 = N[(-s - 1/n + 1/(1 - B/A)), 30]
"Part 2:"
Clear[s, A, B, n, z, k, rho];
n = Prime[10]; Reduce[
 rho == s + 1/n + 1/(1 - A/B) && 
  s + 1/n + 1/(1 - A/B) == Conjugate[-s - 1/n + 1/(1 - B/A)] && 
  B != 0, Re[rho]]
"Mathematica end"
```

Answer (score 1):

Let $s$ be:
$$s=c+i d$$

and let the ratio $$\frac{A}{B}=a+i b$$

then $$\frac{B}{A}=\frac{1}{a+i b}$$

The formulas then become:

$$\rho_1=\frac{1}{1-(a+i b)}+\frac{1}{n}+c+i d$$

$$\rho_2=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{a+i b}}-\frac{1}{n}-(c+i d)$$

Formulas for imaginary parts:
$$\Im(\rho_1) = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{1-(a+i b)}+(c+i d)+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{1-(a-i b)}+(c-i d)+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{i 2}$$
$$\Im(\rho_2) = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{a+i b}}-(c+i d)-\frac{1}{n}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{a-i b}}-(c-i d)-\frac{1}{n}\right)}{i 2}$$

which when simplifying becomes:

$$\Im(\rho_1) = \frac{b}{(a-1)^2+b^2}+d$$

$$\Im(\rho_2) =-\frac{b}{(a-1)^2+b^2}-d$$

From which one sees that: $$\Im(\rho_1) = -\Im(\rho_2)$$

---

One can repeat for the real parts:

Formulas for real parts:
$$\Re(\rho_1) = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{1-(a+i b)}+(c+i d)+\frac{1}{n}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{1-(a-i b)}+(c-i d)+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{2}$$
$$\Re(\rho_2) = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{a+i b}}-(c+i d)-\frac{1}{n}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{a-i b}}-(c-i d)-\frac{1}{n}\right)}{2}$$

which simplifies to:

$$\Re(\rho_1) =\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{2-2 a}{(a-1)^2+b^2}+2 c+\frac{2}{n}\right)$$

$$\Re(\rho_2) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{2 (a-1)}{(a-1)^2+b^2}-2 c-\frac{2}{n}+2\right)$$

Adding together:
$$\Re(\rho_1) + \Re(\rho_2)$$

$$\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{2-2 a}{(a-1)^2+b^2}+2 c+\frac{2}{n}\right)\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{2 (a-1)}{(a-1)^2+b^2}-2 c-\frac{2}{n}+2\right)\right) = 1$$

Therefore:
$$\Re(\rho_1) + \Re(\rho_2) = 1$$

Comment: What you are saying is that $\rho_1+\rho_2=1$ for complex numbers as above; not sure what this has to do with anything except the trivial identity that $A/(A-B)+B/(A-B)=1$

Comment: I don't claim any kind of progress on the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: Not questioning that just what is the meaning of this question since it it just a trivial identity embellished in various ways; not sure what this has to do with RZ or anything else; you can pick any $A,B$ with trivial restrictions and form your $\rho$  numbers as above and they will add to $1$